# Increase in current after added components

Tags: electric-circuits

[image: Circuit diagram]

I am going though a past paper and in the mark scheme it states that when the switch is closed, the current through R (the resistor) increases, while in X it decreases. I understand that it decreases in X due to the "more paths" available for the charge carriers to travel and so they "split up", however I fail to understand how this affects the current through R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that it decreases in X due to the "more paths" available
>   for the charge carriers to travel and so they "split up"

That's not why the current decreases in X; the current decreases in X because there is less voltage across X.

Why is there less voltage across X?  *Because there's more current through R*.

Why is there more current through R?  Because the current through R is the *sum* of the currents through X and Y.

---

Think about it this way.  For simplicity, stipulate that X and Y are identical and further stipulate that the current through R does *not* change when the switch is closed.  It follows that the current through X will be cut by half when the switch is closed (the other half is through Y).

But that would mean that the voltage across X (and hence Y since they are in parallel) would be *less* than before.

But if the voltage across X is less than before, the voltage across R is greater than before (the sum of the voltage across X and R must be the constant $V$) which, by Ohm's law, requires that the current through R has *increased* rather than remained constant as stipulated.

Thus, we cannot stipulate that the current through R does not change when the switch is closed without reaching a contradiction so it must be that the current through R does in fact increase when the switch is closed.